# Low poly bake causing deformation around edges

Tags: texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I am baking a low poly to high mesh and everything baked fine except for the edges. Does anyone know how to fix the edges so that they don't deform like this? Here is a link to the file if you'd like to check it out.

Ive attached photos of the low poly mesh as well and what the normal map distortion looks like as well as the high poly mesh (last photo).
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the first image the low-poly with the baked normal map or the low-poly and high-poly overlapping when they are in the same spot? Have you used Extrusion?

Comment: that looks like a cage problem. try messing with the settings of the size of the cage.

Comment: @Blunder the first image is the low poly with the normal map. The high poly is hidden in that image

Comment: Can you add the link to the file that you mentioned? I guess you have forgotten to add it.

Comment: @Blunder sorry I thought I added it, I I had to rebake and change the image texture to non color then it worked fine

Comment: ah ok, so it was the infamous *Non-Color* data issue with the normal map. Glad you solved it.